# Can't take capital even with casus belli

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Why is it that I can't take the capital of Aragon (Valencia) even when I have casus belli on Valencia?  I've done some searching and some people say you need to take all nearby zones as well, but I HAVE taken all of them including the bordering island zone. Valencia still doesn't show up as an annexation option when I sue for peace.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135783/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-province-to-show-up-as-a-viable-cede-option-when/136786#136786

Answer (score 3):

You need to take all the surrounding provinces in a previous war, and then you can take the capital. Occupying the provinces is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Captial provinces cannot be taken in a normal war unless; it is the opposition's only province ie: the last county, or if it's an isolated exclave, with subsuming this to be the only war-goal.

> [In war: If a capital is occupied during a war, it will count for a greater warscore because of its value. It also generally cannot be claimed as part of a peace deal unless it is the very last province of the country; as part of an annexation; or if it is isolated and the sole aim of the war.](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Capital)

Comment: Incorrect. You can take capital provinces if they are locked in (do not border any other friendly territory).

Comment: That is only true if it 'locked in' **and** the sole aim of the war

Comment: Good point about the war goal. Turned the -1 into a +1! :D

Comment: Cheers, I realised that my answer initially was vague, went and sourced that above and corrected :)